# how to set 2nd datepicker minDate = 1st Datepicker+ 1yr?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to set mindate 2nd datepicket = 1st Datepicker + 1yr. and also restict to not select 2nd datepicker until 1st datepicker selected?

I am trying this

```
  $("#BeginDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:2040',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        beforeShow: function () {
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 9999);
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
            $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate",
            $("#BeginDate").datepicker("getDate") +"1yr" **"{her we need set date}"**);
        },
```

Comment: Did you check my answer? Please accept & vote it if it's correct. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setFullYear` method of the `Date` object for that:

```js
$("#BeginDate").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: '1900:2040',
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  beforeShow: function () {
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('z-index', 9999);
  },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var d = new Date($("#BeginDate").datepicker("getDate"));
    d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + 1);
    $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", d);
  }
});
$("#EndDate").datepicker()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Begin: <input type="text" id="BeginDate"></p>
<p>End: <input type="text" id="EndDate"></p>
```